# How can a disable and show a loading sign in place of a "a href" tag until the whole page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using a href tag to open a dialog box using bootstrap in which some data is to be shown using jquery but i want that the dialog box must not be opened until all the data is loaded in the web page in which this a href is used.

The hyperlink works before the page is loaded but the data is not fetched into the dialog box and not shown into the dialog box. I want that until my whole web page is loaded, this a href must be disabled or a loading sign must come in place of this a href.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Below is the href which i am using to open a dialog box.

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $row_rsnf['autoid'];?>" class="btn-primary lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row_rsnf['autoid']?>">Comments:</a>
```

Comment: It would be more interesting if you showed us the actual code that loads the content in the modal

Comment: as adeneo said, show us the code.. Anyway, you may take a look at the comfort jQuery prototype called ".ready": http://api.jquery.com/ready/ Also, check the ".load" prototype too: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: I suppose if the user disabled JavaScript then they are equally screwed over...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the link before document is ready and show some loader instead

```
<a href="#" style="display: none;" id="<?php echo $row_rsnf['autoid'];?>" class="btn-primary lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row_rsnf['autoid']?>">Comments:</a>
<div id="loader">loading...</div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      //when ready show the button
      $('.btn-primary.lg').show();

      //hide the loader 
      $('#loader').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hide the link and show a loader gif using Jquery, the Jquery Dialog has the event listeners built in to incorporate this: open & beforeClose to put back the link and hide the gif.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/